# scanning a 128 bit input represented in 32 hex values

Tags: c, string, char, hex, scanf

I need to scan the 32 hex number from command line and populated it into a uint8_t [16] array, I tried scanning the string and convert it to hex but its really a hassle since i cant find a function that does that, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already and how it got failed.

Comment: Please show an example string like recveived from the command line.

Comment: daec3055df058e1c39e814ea76f6747e

Comment: Did you mean you did not find [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint8_t get_int(char c)
{
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return      c - '0';
  if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return 10 + c - 'A';
  if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return 10 + c - 'a';
  return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buff[33];
    size_t size;
    size_t i;
    uint8_t *output;

    fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);
    size = strlen(buff) / 2;
    output = malloc(size);

    for (i= 0; i < size; ++i)
      output[i] = get_int(buff[2*i]) * 16 + get_int(buff[2*i+1]);

    for (i= 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%u ", output[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

[ideone link](//ideone.com/fgI5gz)